# making a circular hole out of an existing circle

Tags: modeling, mesh

Disclosure; I am quite knew to blender and have only worked with it for å few hours, but I can not seem to find an answer to my specific problem anywhere online.

I am trying to cut a circular hole in a box, and have already duplicated the circle, but I do not know how to remove the inner part of the circle and connect the insides to the pillars. Please help me.
[image: picture of problem]

[image: picture of problem]

Comment: you can't create a hole without at least one edge connecting the hole to the outer border, so use a knife to create this edge.

Comment: you should separate that ring of faces as new mesh with P, scale up in Y it and use in a boolean modifier again on the main object... I guess that's how you did first hole

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a hole without at least one edge connecting the hole to the outer border, so use a knife to create this edge:

[image]